# Resources To Start a Web Server

Tags: sockets, resources, webserver

I want to start the development of a web server using the Scheme language, but I need to have the basics knowledge of the web server, using the sockets and a little about the optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also look at [Implementation and Use of the PLT Scheme Web Server](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Papers/Published/khmgpf-impl-use-plt-web-server-journal/paper.pdf) which describes somebody building one.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the HTTP protocol can be seen in the RFC document located at  [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Answer (score 1):

These could be good starting points:

- [Apache Source Code Repository](http://www.apache.org/dev/version-control.html)
- [Lighttpd code repository](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository)